# Removing the seconds from a Django TimeField when a user is editing the form field

Tags: python, django

I have a model that's called Event where a user can add an event_name, event_time, and event_location.

The event_time is a Django Timefield

The user can also edit the time as they see fit. However, when I let the user edit the field, the field shows up like this:

```
10:00:00
```

I know that this is how it's stored internally, but is there way to remove the seconds when the user edits the field? Like this :

```
10:00
```

Forms.py:

```
time_widget = forms.widgets.TimeInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'ex: 10:30AM'})
valid_time_formats = ['%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p']

class EditEventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    event_time = forms.TimeField(required=True, widget=time_widget, help_text='ex: 10:30AM', input_formats=valid_time_formats)
```

views.py relevant code:

```
...
form = EditEventForm(request.POST or None, instance = instance)
...
```

**Update**
I want to allow the user to enter times like 10:00 or 10:00AM. So I need all these formats: `'%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p'`

It would be nice if the text in the form field showed the time with the time a day (e.g. 10:00AM), but the seconds removed would also suffice (e.g. 10:00).

Answer (score 2):

Can you in your form, do:

```
event_time = forms.TimeField(widget=forms.TimeInput(format='%H:%M'))
```

Comment: Yes, but this is the case where the user already has submitted the form the first time, and now wants to edit the event_time. I'll post my relevant forms.py code

Comment: How does that matter if you create or edit? The widget should work as long as you use the same form isn't it?

Comment: Because I've tried it and I still get this display: 10:00:00. Maybe there's an issue with my forms.py?

Comment: It should work: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/widgets/#timeinput. I couldn't find the reason, unless you render the form in your template differently. Maybe show us your template code as well?

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I'll look into this. With your answer, I think it's an issue with 'format =' vs 'input_formats =' . I'll probably just use js if I can't figure it out with the docs.

Comment: If you get rid of your `input_formats` parameter for now, does the field show correctly? If so, you might just validate it in your `clean()` method.

Comment: This would work, but I want to allow the user to enter times like 10:00 or 10:00AM. So i need all these formats: '%H:%M', '%I:%M%p', '%I:%M %p'

Answer (score 0):

I just added js until I find a better solution:

```
      var event_time = $('#id_event_time').val();
      if (event_time.length > 5) {
        var new_event_time = event_time.slice(0,-3)
        $('#id_event_time').val(new_event_time);
      }
```